I cannot connect to database using WSL Ubuntu, but everything works on windows
I get
"Exception has occurred: OperationalError
(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "stat-hh-postgresql" to address: Name or service not known"
when I run a function with Ubuntu but the same function works well with windows.
Also another function that fails to connect to MySQL database via Ubuntu, works well with windows.
def connect_to_modelDB():
        
        engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@stat-hh-postgresql:5432/DBname")
        modelDB = engine.connect()
        return modelDB

geos = query_table_from_modelDB("geos")

I get "Exception has occurred: OperationalError
(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "stat hh postgresql" to address: Name or service not known
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "stat-hh-postgresql" to address: Name or service not known"

stat-hh-postgresql cannot be resolved by your ubuntu system's DNS resolver.
try ping stat-hh-postgresql from ubuntu.  Bet that does not work, but works from windows.

You are right. I'm really new to this, how can I correct the issue?

This pointed me in the write direction. I manually mapped "stat-hh-postgresql" to the ip address in the /etc/hosts and it worked.
